# How to call a function of embedded swf from wrapper flash movie?

Tags: actionscript-3

I created a test.fla containing a rectangle symbol with instance name "mc" and on the first frame some as3 code:

```
import com.greensock.*;
function forward() {
    TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {x:132});
}
function backward() {
    TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {x:12});
}
```

This fla is now published as test.swf.

Then I created a **wrapper_fla**, created new symbol and inside this symbol imported test.swf. Named the symbol instance "swf".

Then added two buttons: btnForward and btnBackward to wrapper_fla (outside the symbol) and this code to 1st frame of wrapper_fla:

```
btnForward.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandlerForward);
function mouseDownHandlerForward(event:MouseEvent):void {
    swf.forward();
}
btnBackward.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandlerBackward);
function mouseDownHandlerBackward(event:MouseEvent):void {
    swf.backward();
}
```

When I test the movie and click on btnForward, there is an error:

> TypeError: Error #1006: forward is not a function.
>       at wrapper_fla::MainTimeline/mouseDownHandlerForward()

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Any detiles about loading ? You should probably write it like that : loader.content.forward();

Comment: what is `swf` ? If `swf = MovieClip(loader.content);` then `swf.forward()` should work